# How to truncate the decimal values in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

My query would be like this,

```
declare @Q numeric = 3960 
declare @S varchar(10) = 2.5
select @Q*(1+(convert(float,@S)/100))
```

Based on the `@S` value result may have `n` number of decimals but I just need to remove decimal part alone from the result irrespective of number of decimals. I tried many ways but its not working for all `@Q` and `@S` combinations.

```
SELECT
   ROUND(@Q * (1 + ((convert(float,@S)) / 100)),0,1)   ,
   ROUND(CAST (@Q*(1+(convert(float,@S)/100)) AS decimal (6,2)),1,0)
```

Answer (score 0):

What about ROUND() function with Only `0` as arguments. This will round the value to 0 decimal places.

```
declare @Q numeric = 3960 
declare @S varchar(10) = 2.554
select ROUND(@Q*(1+(convert(float,@S)/100)), 0)
```

If you want to simple truncate any decimals simply use FLOOR() function.

```
declare @Q numeric = 3960 
declare @S varchar(10) = 2.554
select FLOOR(@Q*(1+(convert(float,@S)/100)))
```

Comment: NO it should work for any number of decimals. try @S=3.333 its rounding off.

Comment: @Santhosh_ms3 Using floor function will truncate any decimals. if this is what you are  looking for.

Comment: Try for the values @Q = 3960 and @S = 2.5, expected result is 4059.

Comment: If you use ROUND function it will return 4509 and truncating will return you 4058, you decide whether to truncate(Floor) the results or or ROUND them.

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to REMOVE the values to the right of the decimal in @S and then multiply that value against @Q:

```
DECLARE @Q NUMERIC = 3960
DECLARE @S VARCHAR(10) = 2.5

SELECT Floor(@Q * (CONVERT(FLOAT, @S)))
```

Edit: As M.Ali pointed out, the FLOOR() function will remove any decimals without changing the value to the left of the decimal point.

Comment: Please read my question, i need to multiply and then remove decimals from the resultant value.

Comment: Based on your comment to M.Ali, you are asking a very different question than is stated in the actual problem.  4,950 = 3,960 * 1.25 and the only connection between those values (4,950, 3,960, and 1.25) and the original problem is @Q = 3,960, desired outcome is 4,950, and 1.25 = (1 + (@S / 10)).  Please clarify the problem statement.

Comment: Ignore the previous comment ... I transposed some numbers when reading the other comments (4950 vs. 4059).

Answer (score 0):

I got it. Problem is with Float datatype.

```
declare @Q numeric = 3960 
declare @S varchar(10) = 2.5
select 
3960*(1+(convert(decimal(18,2),@S)/100)),
floor(@Q*(1+(convert(decimal(18,2),@S)/100)))
```

Please refer this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187912.aspx. Thanks for your time.